# Fast and simple binary concatenate files in Powershell

Tags: powershell

What's the best way of concatenating binary files using Powershell?
I'd prefer a one-liner that simple to remember and fast to execute.

The best I've come up with is:

```
gc -Encoding Byte -Path ".\File1.bin",".\File2.bin" | sc -Encoding Byte new.bin
```

This seems to work ok, but is terribly slow with large files.

Answer (score 39, accepted):

The approach you're taking is the way I would do it in PowerShell.  However you should use the -ReadCount parameter to improve perf.  You can also take advantage of positional parameters to shorten this even further:

```
gc File1.bin,File2.bin -Encoding Byte -Read 512 | sc new.bin -Encoding Byte
```

<sup>*Editor's note*: In the cross-platform [PowerShell (Core)](https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell/) edition  (version 6 and up), `-AsByteStream` must now be used instead of `-Encoding Byte`; also, the `sc` alias for the [`Set-Content`](https://learn.microsoft.com/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.management/set-content) cmdlet has been removed.</sup>

Regarding the use of the -ReadCount parameter, I did a blog post on this a while ago that folks might find useful - [Optimizing Performance of Get Content for Large Files](http://rkeithhill.wordpress.com/2007/06/17/optimizing-performance-of-get-content-for-large-files/).

Comment: I just ran this on my example files and the command went from taking 9 minutes to 3 seconds with the inclusion of the -read param. This is on a x25m drive. Nice. You get my accept.

Comment: Just used your one-liner to join a 4.4gb iso spanned over 23 files. Reassembled the file fine, and took 35 minutes on my laptop using 1024 byte blocks.

Comment: I'm guessing this works because the pipe is sending .net objects to sc?  When I tried to pipe binary data to a c program, I noticed that I only got the first 7 bits of each byte, since "|" was invokes encoding.

Comment: No longer works in PowerShell 6/7. Byte is not an accepted encoding. `Get-Content: Cannot process argument transformation on parameter 'Encoding'. 'Byte' is not a supported encoding name. For information on defining a custom encoding, see the documentation for the Encoding.RegisterProvider method. (Parameter 'name')`

Answer (score 32):

It's not Powershell, but if you have Powershell you also have the command prompt:

```
copy /b 1.bin+2.bin 3.bin
```

As Keith Hill pointed out, if you really need to run it from inside Powershell, you can use:

```
cmd /c copy /b 1.bin+2.bin 3.bin
```

Comment: copy is an intrinsic command in cmd.exe. You would have to execute cmd /c copy /b 1.bin+2.bin 3.bin

Comment: Nice simple solution, works on any windows computer.
Upvoted but accept to Keith since I asked for PS version. Thx

Comment: Note also that `copy` supports wildcards. So `copy /b *.bin out.bin` will concatenate all your bin-files and the output will be very fast (i.e. much faster than with PowerShell).

Comment: Thanks... Its about a billion times faster than the accepted anwser ;). I missed the "cmd /c" when trying to run it from PowerShell. Sometimes the old ways are still the best.

Answer (score 6):

I had a similar problem recently, where I wanted to append two large (2GB) files into a single file (4GB).

I tried to adjust the -ReadCount parameter for Get-Content, however I couldn't get it to improve my performance for the large files.

I went with the following solution:

```
function Join-File (
    [parameter(Position=0,Mandatory=$true,ValueFromPipeline=$true)]
    [string[]] $Path,
    [parameter(Position=1,Mandatory=$true)]
    [string] $Destination
)
{
    write-verbose "Join-File: Open Destination1 $Destination"
    $OutFile = [System.IO.File]::Create($Destination)
    foreach ( $File in $Path ) {
        write-verbose "   Join-File: Open Source $File"
        $InFile = [System.IO.File]::OpenRead($File)
        $InFile.CopyTo($OutFile)
        $InFile.Dispose()
    }
    $OutFile.Dispose()
    write-verbose "Join-File: finished"
}
```

**Performance:**

- `cmd.exe /c copy file1+file2 File3`       around 5 seconds (Best)
- `gc file1,file2 |sc file3`       around 1100 seconds (yuck)
- `join-file File1,File2 File3`       around 16 seconds (OK)

Comment: cmd.exe copy is many times faster than native PS cmdlets - 1.2MB/s versus >120Mb/s. Not surprising considering how Get-Content works even with the -ReadCound parameter

Answer (score 3):

Performance is very much dependent on the buffer size used. Those are fairly small by default. Concatenating 2x2GB files I'd take a buffersize of about 256kb. Going larger might sometimes fail, smaller and you'll get less throughput than your drive is capable of.

With `gc` that'd be with `-ReadCount` not simply `-Read` (PowerShell 5.0):

```
gc -ReadCount 256KB -Path $infile -Encoding Byte | ...
```

Plus I found `Add-Content` to be better and going file-by-file for a lot of small files, because piping only a moderate amount of data (200MB) I found my computer going oom, PowerShell freezing and CPU at full.

Although `Add-Content` randomly fails a few times for a few hundred files with an error about the destination file being in use, so I added a while loop and a try catch:

```
# Empty the file first
sc -Path "$path\video.ts" -Value @() -Encoding Byte 
$tsfiles | foreach {    
    while ($true) {
        try { # I had -ReadCount 0 because the files are smaller than 256KB
            gc -ReadCount 0 -Path "$path\$_" -Encoding Byte | `
                Add-Content -Path "$path\video.ts" -Encoding Byte -ErrorAction Stop
            break;
        } catch {
        }
    }
}
```

Using a file stream is much faster still. You cannot  specify a buffer size with `[System.IO.File]::Open` but you can with `new [System.IO.FileStream]` like so:

```
# $path = "C:\"
$ins = @("a.ts", "b.ts")
$outfile = "$path\out.mp4"
$out = New-Object -TypeName "System.IO.FileStream" -ArgumentList @(
    $outfile, 
    [System.IO.FileMode]::Create,
    [System.IO.FileAccess]::Write,
    [System.IO.FileShare]::None,
    256KB,
    [System.IO.FileOptions]::None)
try {
    foreach ($in in $ins) {
        $fs = New-Object -TypeName "System.IO.FileStream" -ArgumentList @(
            "$path\$in", 
            [System.IO.FileMode]::Open,
            [System.IO.FileAccess]::Read,
            [System.IO.FileShare]::Read,
            256KB,
            [System.IO.FileOptions]::SequentialScan)
        try {
            $fs.CopyTo($out)
        } finally {
            $fs.Dispose()
        }
    }
} finally {
    $out.Dispose()
}
```

Comment: One is guessing that this is a very similar method used by cmd.exe copy command

Answer (score 0):

you could also use this method to concatenate any type of files.
not that fast but just another way to do it

```
cmd /c type file1 file2 file3 file4 > outfile
```

or you can use jobs to speed up things if more than one copy task exist.

```
$jobs=@()
$Files=@( @("d:\path\app1.rar","d:\path\app2.rar","d:\path\app3.rar","d:\path\appOutFile.rar"),@("c:\users\user\desktop\file1.iso","c:\users\user\desktop\file2.iso","c:\users\user\desktop\file3.iso","c:\users\user\desktop\isoOutFile.iso"),@("c:\users\user\video\video1.mp4","c:\users\user\video\video2.mp4","c:\users\user\video\mp4OutFile.mp4"))
$totalMb=0
foreach($Group in $Files){
    $sources=$Group|select -first ($Group.Length-1)
    $sources|%{ $totalMb+=(get-Item $_).Length/1mb }
    $sources=$(($sources -replace "^|$",[char]34)-join"+")
    $destination=[char]34+($Group|select -last 1)+[char]34
    cmd /c type nul> $destination
    $jobs+=start-job -scriptBlock { param($src,$dst) &cmd.exe "/c copy /b $src $dst" } -arg $sources,$destination 
    # $jobs+=start-job -scriptBlock { param($src,$dst) &cmd.exe "/c type $($src -replace '`"\+`"','`" `"') > $dst" } -arg $sources,$destination
}

"Total MegaBytes To Concatenate is: $( [math]::Truncate($totalMb) )MB"
while ( $($jobs|% {$_.state -eq "running"}) -contains $true ) {"still concatenating files...";start-sleep -s 2}

"jobs finished !!!";$jobs|receive-job;$jobs|remove-job -force
```