# combining multiples into one after user selection

Tags: powershell, cmd

Im looking for a powershell script which prompts user to select multiple files.  After selection is confirmed, I want to combine all selected files into one file.
Here is what I could manage so far

```
Function Get-FileName($initialDirectory)
{
    [System.Reflection.Assembly]::LoadWithPartialName("System.windows.forms") | Out-Null

    $OpenFileDialog = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.OpenFileDialog
    $OpenFileDialog.initialDirectory = $initialDirectory
    $OpenFileDialog.filter = "TXT (*.txt;*.log)| *.txt;*.log"
    $openFileDialog.MultiSelect = $true
    $OpenFileDialog.ShowDialog() | Out-Null
    $OpenFileDialog.FileNames
}
$inputfiles = Get-FileName "C:\temp"
$inputfiles
cmd /c copy /b $inputfiles out.txt
```

The files are usually big text/log files with millions of lines in each file and so far copy via cmd is the fastest way I know of to combine big files.
The current script copies only first file in `$inputfiles` .  How can I get this to work to combine all files?

Comment: Also read this related post, since your files seem to be huge: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1783554/fast-and-simple-binary-concatenate-files-in-powershell

Comment: I used a solution in a comment from that question only to merge my files via cmd

Answer (score 0):

This is an simple example how you can do it. I have replaced your openfiledialog with out-gridview

```
#Get files and prompt them in Grid-View
$Files = Get-ChildItem -Path 'C:\temp\SC Test' -Recurse -Include *.txt, *.log | Select-Object -Property Name, DirectoryName, FullName | Out-GridView -PassThru -Title "select files to merge"
#path for the new file with the content
$MergedFilePath = "C:\temp\merged.txt"

#Loop selected files from gridview
Foreach($File in $Files){
    #Get text from file and write the text to the new file
    Get-Content -Path $File.FullName | Out-File -FilePath $MergedFilePath -Encoding utf8 -Append
}
```

Comment: I just tested your script on 7 files.  it took +3 minutes to complete.  TotalMinutes      : 3.149990845
TotalSeconds      : 188.9994507

using cmd it takes like TotalMinutes      : 0.00320825666666667
TotalSeconds      : 0.1924954

thats why I went with my approach.  I just cant seem to figure out how to merge file names in a array/variable via cmd

Comment: This merge part should be faster. Get-Content -Path $Files.FullName | Add-Content -Path $MergedFilePath -Encoding utf8 in this case you can remove the loop and note that the file $MergedFilePath must exist