# Powershell call cmd.exe command like copy /b

Tags: powershell, cmd

I saw this already [Fast and simple binary concatenate files in Powershell](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1783554/fast-and-simple-binary-concatenate-files-in-powershell)

I'm not interested by the answer above I'm interested about what's wrong with syntax below :

when I call a `cmd.exe` command like `copy /b`:

```
function join-file {
   copy /b $($args[0])+$($args[1]) $($args[2])
}
```

I get an error `Copy-Item : A positional parameter cannot be found`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As the error alludes to, `copy` is actually just an alias for `Copy-Item` and it does not have a `/b` parameter. You can call cmd to use its copy command.

```
function join-file {
   cmd /c copy /b $($args[0])+$($args[1]) $($args[2])
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Note: This answer complements [Doug Maurer's helpful answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/64827869/45375), which provides an effective solution (for file names without spaces).

There's a subtlety in how PowerShell parses *unquoted* compound tokens such as `$($args[0])+$($args[1])` (by compound token I mean directly concatenated distinct syntax constructs):

**`$($args[0])+$($args[1])` results in *two* arguments**<sup>[1]</sup> - although with the specific command at hand (`cmd.exe`'s internal `copy` command) that happens *not* to be a problem:

- Argument 1: The value of `$($args[0])`
- Argument 2: A verbatim `+` directly followed by the value of `$($args[1])`

To avoid this problem, enclose the whole compound token in `"..."`, so as to predictably treat it as an [expandable string](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40445998/45375).

---

The upshot:

- To be safe, ***use double-quoting (`"..."`) explicitly* to enclose *compound tokens* that involve variable references or subexpressions**.
- By contrast, **to reference a *variable* or even *method call* *in isolation*, neither quoting nor enclosing in `$(...)`, the [subexpression operator](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Operators#subexpression-operator--), are needed**.

Applied naively to your command (see the better solution below):

```
# Note: See better solution below.
function join-file {
   # Note the "..." around the first argument, and the absence of quoting
   # and $(...) around the second.
   cmd /c copy /b "$($args[0])+$($args[1])" $args[2]
}
```

However, **if `$args[0]` or `$($args[1])` contained *spaces*, the `copy` command would malfunction**; it is therefore **more robust to pass the file names and the `+` as *separate* arguments**, which `copy` also supports:

```
function join-file {
   # Pass the arguments individually, which obviates the need for quoting
   # and $(...) altogether:
   cmd /c copy /b $args[0] + $args[1] $args[2]
}
```

---

<sup>[1] You can verify this as follows: `$arr='foo', 'bar'; cmd /c echo $($arr[0])+$($arr[1])`, which yields: `foo +bar` (note the space).</sup>