# Powershell calling cmd with single quote

Tags: powershell, cmd

I wanted to do the same as [Powershell call cmd.exe command like copy /b](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64827770/powershell-call-cmd-exe-command-like-copy-b) but now I have problem with quote : ' was unexpected at this time.

I tried to escape with \ but it's worse

```
function concat-filenames {
   cmd.exe --% /c (echo file '$($args[0])' & echo file '$($args[0])' )>list.txt
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**`--%`, the [stop-parsing symbol](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Parsing), *cannot be combined with PowerShell variables and expressions***, because it passes the remainder of the command line through to the target executable - `cmd.exe` in this case - *as-is*, the only exception being the expansion (interpolation) of `cmd.exe` style *environment-variable references*, such as `%USERNAME%`.

Generally, **`--%` comes with many limitations** - see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42601912/45375).

Something like the following should work; note that `&` must be quoted in order to  be passed through to `cmd.exe`, whereas `>`, due to being unquoted, is interpeted by PowerShell.

```
function concat-filenames {
  cmd.exe /c echo file $args[0] '&' echo file $args[0] > list.txt
}
```

Note that in `cmd.exe` trailing spaces after an `echo` command, before a subsequent operator (such as `&` or `>`), become part of the output.

If you meant to pass the single quotes as *part of the value* (as opposed to their *syntactic* use as a PowerShell string literal), use [expandable strings](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40445998/45375) (`"..."`):

```
function concat-filenames {
  cmd.exe /c echo file "'$($args[0])'" '&' echo file "'$($args[0])'" > list.txt
}
```

Note that in both cases PowerShell performs *re-quoting on demand* behind the scenes: if the *expanded* (interpolated) argument value contains *spaces*, it is wrapped in double quotes (`"..."`).

Answer (score 1):

Please try to load/use the **raw**-content.

By default, Get-Content parses (or tries to) the input as an array of type X (commonly as an array of String).

After a short test .. as Byte (with PS 5.1 using **"-Encoding Byte"** and with PS 6+ using **"-AsByteStream"**) the PowerShell engine streams that "parsed" input to the pipeline not as a whole. (The PS6+ parameter name indicates that already).

Therefore try to use the "-Raw" parameter for that. Since you don't want to loop trough the input in any way you don't need an enumerable object. You need it raw for performance.

Test the following:

**PS 5.1**

```bsh
Get-Content $args[0], $args[1] -Encoding Byte -Raw | Set-Content -Path 'output.txt' -Encoding Byte
```

**PS 6+**

```bsh
Get-Content $args[0], $args[1] -AsByteStream -Raw | Set-Content -Path 'output.txt' -AsByteStream
```

PS:
The memory usage will be higher than the default streaming method. If your binary files are not that big, this shouldn't be an issue.

Comment: Note that you're not answering the question at hand, but a different question that the question body merely _links  to_.